# How to abstract interface method whose param is derived-class-dependent in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two version of data manager, and an interface to abstract these two managers. All these two managers take the data's description as string, hiding the specific data structure.

Now I need to add a method with a param of `Action<Item>` (rather than `Action<string>` with `string` stores the description), this action is passed to SDK which cannot be modified.

In this case, the `Action<Item>` varies according to the specific implementation of `Item`. How to add this method in C# way?

---

Here is the example

1. The interface of different data manager

```
// the interface
interface IContentManager
{
    void UpdateProduct(string id, string productDescription);

    // TODO: public void ApplyForAll(Action<???> op)
}
```

2. The first version of data manager based on a database SDK

The database SDK provides these classes which cannot be modified

```
class ProductItem { }
class ProductDBWriter
{
    // this method cannot be modified
    public void ApplyForAll(Action<ProductItem> op) { }
}
```

The data manager based on database SDK

```
class DBContentManager
{
    void UpdateProduct(string id, string productDescription) { }

    public void ApplyForAll(Action<ProductItem> op)
    {
        _writer.ApplyForAll(op);
    }

    private ProductDBWriter _writer;
}
```

3. The second version of data manager, a lightweight version

```
class ProductItemSlim { }

class SlimContentManager
{
    void UpdateProduct(string id, string productDescription) { }

    // TODO: public void ApplyForAll(Action<???> op)
}
```

The question is: what is the C# way to abstract the `ApplyForAll` method?

Comment: `IContentManager<TItem>`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to create an interface that depends on an unknown type. This is exactly what gernerics is made for. Assume you have a `IContentManager<T>`. Then you can pass an `Action<T>` in `ApplyForAll` and e.g. your `SlimContentManager` could then implement `IContentManager<SlimContent>`.